# Using dynamic programming with Scala to solve the Mixture from CodeChef

Tags: algorithm, scala, optimization, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve the following [codechef problem](http://www.codechef.com/problems/MIXTURES) using scala. The statement of the problem is as follows:

> Harry Potter has n mixtures in front of him, arranged in a row. Each
>   mixture has one of 100 different colors (colors have numbers from 0 to
>   99).
>
> He wants to mix all these mixtures together. At each step, he is going
>   to take two mixtures that stand next to each other and mix them
>   together, and put the resulting mixture in their place.
>
> When mixing two mixtures of colors a and b, the resulting mixture will
>   have the color (a+b) mod 100.
>
> Also, there will be some smoke in the process. The amount of smoke
>   generated when mixing two mixtures of colors a and b is a*b.
>
> Find out what is the minimum amount of smoke that Harry can get when
>   mixing all the mixtures together.

The sample answer provided is as follows:

> Input:
>
> ```
> 2 
> 18 
> 19 
> 3
> 40
> 60
> 20
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 342
> 2400
> ```
>
> In the second test case, there are two possibilities:
>
> ```
> first mix 40 and 60 (smoke: 2400), getting 0, then mix 0 and 20 (smoke: 0); total amount of smoke is 2400
> first mix 60 and 20 (smoke: 1200), getting 80, then mix 40 and 80 (smoke: 3200); total amount of smoke is 4400
> ```
>
> The first scenario is the correct approach since it minimizes the
>   amount of smoke produced.

I understand that this can be solved using dynamic programming but I am having trouble approaching this problem and expressing the algorithm in scala.

Here's how I am thinking about this problem, in some kind of a lookup structure(Array,Map with Tuple(Int,Int) as key) store all the calculated values for mixing two colors

This can be accomplished by the following pseudo-code:

```
for(colors1<-1 through n)
   for(colors2<-k through n)
      if(color1 != color2)
          //Check if color1,color2 combination exists as (color1,color2) or (color2,color1)    
          Map(color1,color2) = (color1+color2)%100
```

Once all the initial colors have been calculated, now we need to consider the order in which we mix up the colors taking into account the smoke produced. This is where I am having issues. I am hitting a wall trying to formulate the sub-structure that will provide the minimum smoke produced.

It will be great to get some guidance here.

Thanks

Comment: Even I have started to feel that modelling the problem for dynamic programming in terms of Scala is a bit difficult as compared with an imperative language that uses loops with mutable data structures more frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the following dynamic programming solution. It's also available as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/2509688).

```
/** Find the minimum amount of smoke (second) and resulting color (first) 
    by splitting the sequence at every possible position,
    given `lookup` contains the best mix for subsequence. */
def minSmokeMixtureSingle(s: Seq[Int], lookup: Map[Seq[Int],(Int,Int)])
  : (Int,Int) = 
    if(s.size == 1)
        (s(0),0)
    else if(s.size == 2)
        mix(s(0),s(1))
    else {
        val splits = (1 to (s.size - 1)).map(s.splitAt)
        val mixes = splits.map{ case (s1,s2) => 
            val (c1,sm1) = lookup(s1)
            val (c2,sm2) = lookup(s2)
            val (newColor,newSmoke) = mix(c1,c2)
            (newColor, newSmoke + sm1 + sm2)
        }
        mixes.minBy(_._2)
    }

def mix(m1: Int, m2: Int): (Int,Int) = ((m1+m2) % 100, m1*m2)

def minSmokeMixture(s: Seq[Int]) = {
    //create the mixture sequences with increasing length
    val windows = for(windowSize <- 1 to s.size;
        window <- s.sliding(windowSize) ) yield window
    //go over the sequences and compute the lookup-table
    val lookup = windows.foldLeft(Map.empty[Seq[Int],(Int,Int)]){
        case (lu,seq) => lu + (seq -> minSmokeMixtureSingle(seq,lu))
    }
    //simply lookup the result
    lookup(s)
}

println(minSmokeMixture(Seq(18, 19)))
println(minSmokeMixture(Seq(40, 60, 20)))
```

This can certainly be improved in terms of style.

It produces the correct output for the given examples (second number is smoke, first is final color):

```
(37,342)
(20,2400)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am still mulling over some of the scala syntax but this seems to me the correct way to approach the problem.

Comment: @sc_ray Feel free to ask questions here. There's a lot going on in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think dynamic progamming has much to do with it. I think this is a graph problem, solved with breadth-first search. A straight [shortest path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) problem.

Comment: I don't see the graph search here. So what's the complexity you get? My algorithm has at most `O(n^3)`. I'm too lazy to ponder whether it's lower.

Comment: @ziggystar `O(|E| + |V|log|V|)`, so we need to know how many vertices there can be. The sortest path can have at most `n - 1` vertices, but the actual number of vertices I think is exponential. The number of edges is bound by the number of vertices.